# python: how to add 'unicodedata' module to my current python lib

Tags: python, python-requests

Currently I am using a python module 'requests' to handle some https issue.

My code works well on a windows machine. But when I copy all source codes to a linux machine and run all codes, there was a feedback `ImportError: No module named unicodedata`.

My python version is 2.7.4. But I found 'unicodedata' module first appeared in 2.5. So it is very strange why my current version doesn't include it.

Is there any method to solve this problem without updating the python version? Or say how can I port 'unicodedata' module to my current python lib? Thanks!

Comment: please install `docutils` in linux machine.

Comment: How about installing it the way it is described here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode

Comment: can you give me more detail information?

Comment: do `pip install undecode` on linux machine.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Install `unicodedata`

On some Linux distro (as Fedora-26), `unicodedata` is provided by package `python-libs`

```
sudo dnf install python-libs
```

But you may attempt:

```
pip install unicodedata
```

or if not found:

```
pip install unicodedata2
```

### 2. Locate `unicodedata`

Your `unicodedata.so` (or `unicodedata2.so`) is in system directory:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so
```

If option `--user` used as in `pip install --user unicodedata2`, the library is in user directory:

```
$HOME/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/unicodedata2.so
```

You can use command `locate unicodedata` if you are still looking for this library.

### 3. Fix `ImportError`

To fix the issue `ImportError: No module named unicodedata`, you can create a symbolic link to the `unicodedata.so` library from your application library directory:

```
cd libs
ln -sv /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/* .
```